# Add 2 differents visualforce page to one pDF

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdf

I have 2 VF pages :
- one that display a quote, with repeatable header and repeatable footer (if there is 2 or more pages the header and footer will be displayed on each pages)
- one that I want to put at the end of the previous page : it's just text and I want to append it juste afeter the last page of the quote and I do not want to display the header and the footer on this last page.

For now I have tested this :

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" standardcontroller="Quote" extensions="DevisPDFController" action="{!savePDF}">
   <html>
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .leadTable{
            margin: 10px !important;
        }        
        @page {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            margin-top: 280px;
            padding:0px;
            margin-bottom: 200px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right:20px;


            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }                           
            @bottom-left {   
                content: element(footer);
            } 
        }        
        div.header {
            margin-top:10px;
            position: running(header);
            margin-right: 12px;
            margin-left: 12px;
        }
        div.footer {                    
            position: running(footer);
            margin-left:12px;
            margin-right: 12px;

        }
        .repeatTableHeader{
        -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        }

        .repeatTableHeader {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size:11px;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        .repeatTableHeader thead th{
            border:1px solid black;
            background: #C1C1C1;
            border-right: 0px;
        }

        .lignesPrix,.ligneEntete{
            padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;
        }

        .lignesPrix{
            border-left: 1px solid black;
        }

        .divTable{
            margin-top: 10px;
            border:1px solid black;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
        }

        .pagenumber:before {         
            content: counter(page);      
        }                            
        .pagecount:before {          
            content: counter(pages);     
        }

        .lastPage{
            page: last_page;
            page-break-before: always;
            z-index: 99 !important;
        }

        @page :last {
            @bottom-left {
                content:none;
            }
            @top-center{
                content:none;
            }
        }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body style="font-family:SansSerif !important;margin-left:12px;margin-right:12px;">
        <div class="header">
            <table width="100%" >
                <tr width="100%">
                    <td width="20%" align="left">
                        <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.logo}" width="150" height="150" style="margin-top:-15px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%"></td>
                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-size:12px;">
                         <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="infoDevis">
                            //some values           
                        </apex:panelGrid>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size:10px;">
                <tr width="100%">
                    <td width="800px" align="left" style="border:1px solid black; padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;">
                            //some values
                    </td>
                    <td width="500px" align="left" style="border:1px solid black; padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px; vertical-align:top;">
                        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="info">
                            //some values
                        </apex:panelGrid>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>    

        <div class="footer" >

            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size:11px;">
                <tr width="100%">
                    <td width="800px" align="left" style="border:1px solid black; padding: 10px;">
                        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="info">
                            //some values
                        </apex:panelGrid>
                    </td>
                    <td width="500px" align="left" style="border:1px solid black; padding: 10px; vertical-align:top;">
                        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" styleClass="info">
                            //some values
                        </apex:panelGrid>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>        

            <div style="font-size:8px">Page <span class="pagenumber"/> / <span class="pagecount"/></div> 
        </div>


        <div class="divTable" style="page-break-after:auto;">
            <table class="repeatTableHeader" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                        //some values
                     </tr>  
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     <apex:repeat value="{!lLignesDevis}" var="item" >
                         <tr>
                             //some values
                         </tr>
                     </apex:repeat>
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <div class="lastPage">
       <apex:include pageName="CGV"/> 
    </div>

</apex:page>
```

The problem is that on the lest page (the CGV page) the header and the footer are displaying. And since we can't select the last page of a PDF I don't know how the remove them without also removing them from the other pages (I need to diplay them on all the pages except the last one)

Maybe a javascript solution can do the job ? I didn't know javascrip very well

Comment: Just a note, `@page :last` does not exist as a selector. That is why that is not doing what you expect. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/@page). Also, JavaScript does not run in a PDF context, so JavaScript cannot be a part of the solution here either.

Comment: thanks, yes I tried to put :last but indeed there is no effect...

Comment: @nbrown is there a way to use the pageNumber so if we are at the last page (3 out of 3 for example) then we hide the header and footer ?

Comment: Doubtful, because the CSS implementation used to render PDFs is outdated (CSS 2.1). Maybe you can try out the `-fs-page-sequence` attribute in conjunction with a special `@page :first` rule to see if you can remove the header and footer on the first and last pages. Not completely ideal. See the [Flying Saucer docs](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_43), which is the rendering engine used for PDFs. Your other option is to remove the `@page` rules and insert your headers and footers into the page content.

Comment: What I did long time ago was to have a fixed number of table rows for page 1 and page X. So for each apex:repeat iteration, check if the current row equals the specified n rows per page X, then put a page break, and finally after that print the last page.Not elegant, but did the job.